# Cannot get models thats referencing another model aas foriegn key

Tags: django, django-models

What i want to do is get all userimages that use a particular foriegnkey
I'm doing this by
     User.objects.get(pk=1).profile.friends.all().values_list('userimages')

but then this is what i get. What I find strange is that uservideo model is very similar to userimages and yet userimages cannot be resolved.

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'userimages' into field. Choices are: about_me, display_image, friends, id, nick_name, owner, owner_id, user, user_id, uservideo
```

models

```
class UserImages(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='UserImages')
user=models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name="profile_owner")

# highlighted = models.TextField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
image=models.ImageField()
pub_date=models.DateTimeField(default=now)
class UserVideo(models.Model):

owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='UserVideo')
# highlighted = models.TextField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
user=models.ForeignKey(Profile)
image=models.FileField()
pub_date=models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is:
Select all images from Images object where user has FK:

```
query = UserImages.objects.filter(user=1).all()
```

Comment: Is there a way to get queryset for mulltiple users?

Comment: @prashanthambati Yes, you can use `__in` lookup: `UserImages.objects.filter(user__in=[1, 2, 3])`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get this,you can try this also

```
userObj=User.objects.get(pk=1)
userImages = UserImages.objects.filter(user=userObj)
Images=[]
for userImage in userImages:
    Images.append(userImage.image)
```